# Help in indenting second line under tabular environment

Tags: tables, indentation

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{1ex}} l }
Programming Languages: \ & C, Python \\

Simulation And Modelling Software: \ & GROMACS, VMD, PyMol \\

Bioinformatics Tools: \ & Phytozome, PlantCare, pfam, ExPasy Protoparam, Cello, MEME Suite, Plant Genome Duplication Database, Gene Structure Display Server \\



Electrochemical Technique: \ & Square Wave Voltammetry, Cyclic Voltammetry \\

\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}
```

but outlook looks like this :

```
SKILLS
Programming Languages: C, Python
Simulation And Modelling Software: GROMACS, VMD, PyMol
Bioinformatics Tools: Phytozome, PlantCare, pfam, ExPasy Protoparam, Cello, MEME Suite, Plant Geno
Electrochemical Technique: Square Wave Voltammetry, Cyclic Voltammetry
```

how not to let the big line incomplete, instead start it from second line but just after the word Phytozome

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. By "indenting", do you mean line-breaking?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a `tabular` environment is the best tool for the job at hand. Instead, I'd use a `description` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[noitemsep,before={\raggedright}]
\item[Programming languages] C, Python 
\item[Simulation and modelling software] GROMACS, VMD, PyMol
\item[Bioinformatics tools] Phytozome, PlantCare, pfam, ExPasy Protoparam, Cello, MEME Suite, Plant Genome Duplication Database, Gene Structure Display Server 
\item[Electrochemical technique] Square Wave Voltammetry, Cyclic Voltammetry
\end{description}

\end{document}
```